# JButton mnemonic underline only on ALT key

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mnemonics

```
        JFrame f = new MnemoticTest();          
        JButton b=new JButton("bat");

        b.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(400, 700);
        f.setVisible(true);
```

Hello, I got the above code. When it loads, the 'b' is already underlined.
I want the 'b' to be underlined only when I click alt.

On loading it should show no underline, and when I click alt, the b should show up as underlined

How do we do it?

Comment: Change the look and feel, to one that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, this behavior is only supported by the Windows L&F. So you need to change your L&F to Windows L&F.

If you are working on Windows computer, you can do the following:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If not, you can try the following (I'm not sure whether the Windows L&F will work on non-Windows computer):

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**IMPORTANT**: Setting of L&F should be performed on start of application, when no visual elements have been initialized.

Comment: *"I'm not sure whether the Windows L&F will work on non-Windows computer"* No it won't. Which is kind of fortunate for users on OS X and Unix/Linux who ***don't want to see** another Windows GUI.*

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy 
Works well! thank you for your reply. And how do I click alt one, and all Mnemotic stay underlined. And when I click alt once again, all the Mnemotic are no more underlined??